# Android: bluetooth is very slow if a phone is not connected to PC with debug mode

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth

I have program for arduino. It can transmit image over bluetooth.

1. If I make connection from PC: 3 frames in a second.
2. If I make connection from Android App with USB debug: again 3 frames in a
   second.
3. If I make connection from Android App without USB debug: 1
   frame in 10 seconds.

Does anybody have idea why Android becomes so slow?

Comment: Looks like the issue in default bluetooth baudrate (9600) which is higher when it is connected via USB debug. Strange.....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue using two solutions:

1. Read data from input stream by one: inStream.read()
2. Send any symbol to output stream every 1 second.